# How to update data table by clicking full calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, fullcalendar

I am having a full calendar along with data table to do some functions.
I have a full calendar,few buttons and a data table to highlight selected dates.

At first, I have 2 Individual button **'Working day','off day'**. If I click 'Off day' button and select particular date(cell) on full calendar, that cell background must be changed and the selected date added to my data table. likewise, if I chose 'Working day' button, and click the selected off day cells, the cell's color must change back to white and the data must be removed from my data table. This one works fine for me.

I have one more button **'Load Calendar'** to highlight all the Sundays on selected year and add those 52 data's to my data table. That too works for me.

**The problem is**, After chose for a year, I need to add individual 'off day' button or need to remove few of the highlighted Sundays to working day-when I do this, only calendar cell's color only changed- data not removed from data table, and duplicate data's were added to datatable when clicking 'off/Working day' button more than once.

**Code for button:**

```
 <div class="btn-group">
     <a id="btnWorkingDay" name="btnWorkingDay" class="@*external-event*@ btn btn-block btn-default btn-flat"><span class="hide-on-mobile">Working Day </span></a>
 </div>
 <div class="btn-group">
     <a id="btnOffDay" name="btnOffDay" style="background-color:#1BBF2A;color:white" class="btn btn-block #1BBF2A btn-flat"><span class="hide-on-mobile">Off Day </span></a>
 </div>

**Code for full calendar:**

<div class="box-body no-padding">
    <div id="calendar_full"></div>
</div>
```

**code for button to load full year:**

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a id="btnLoadCalendar" name="btnLoadCalendar" onclick="LoadCalendar1()" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-flat"><span class="hide-on-mobile">Load Calendar </span><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></a>
</div>
```

**code for Data table:**

```
 <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%;" id="CalendarSelection" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-hd">
<thead>

    <tr class="gridheader">
        <td valign="middle" align="center" style="width: 2%;"></td>
        <td style="width: 50%;" class="search_field" id="CalendarDate">Calendar Date</td>
        <td style="width: 50%;" class="search_field" id="Description">Description</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

**Script:**

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var t = $('#CalendarSelection').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [{
            "searchable": false,
            "orderable": false,
            "targets": 0
        }],
       });

    t.on('order.dt search.dt', function () {
        t.column(0, { search: 'applied', order: 'applied' }).nodes().each(function (cell, i) {
            cell.innerHTML = i + 1;
        });
    });
    });

        $(function () {
            var t = $('#CalendarSelection').DataTable();
            var y = new Date().getFullYear();
            t.clear().draw();
            $('#calendar_full').fullCalendar('gotoDate', year);
             select();

            $('.fc-left').remove();
            $('.select_month').addClass('hide');
            $('.fc-today-button').addClass('hide');
            $('.fc-prev-button').addClass('hide');
            $('.fc-next-button').addClass('hide');
        });

     function select() {
            var date = new Date()

            $("#btnWorkingDay").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                $(this).toggleClass("selected");
                $("#btnOffday").removeClass("selected");
              });
            $("#btnOffday").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                $(this).toggleClass("selected");
                $("#btnWorkingDay").removeClass("selected");
            });     
             $('#calendar_full').fullCalendar({
                plugins: ['interaction'],
                header: {
                    center: 'title'
                },
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
                    var t = $('#CalendarSelection').DataTable();

                    if (!$("#btnWorkingDay").hasClass("selected") && !$("#btnOffday").hasClass("selected"))
                        return;

                    var cell = $(this);

                    if ($("#btnWorkingDay").hasClass("selected")) {
                        var backgroundColour = 'white';
                        var description = '';
                    } else if ($("#btnOffday").hasClass("selected")) {
                        var backgroundColour = '#1BBF2A';
                        var description = 'Half Working Day';
                    }

                    cell
                        .css('background-color', backgroundColour)
                        .text(description);
                    if (($('tr[data-date="' + cell.data('date') + '"]').length > 0)) {
                        var data = t.row($('tr[data-date="' + cell.data('date') + '"]')).data();
                        if (cell.text() == '') {
                            t.row($('tr[data-date="' + cell.data('date') + '"]')).remove().draw();
                            return
                        }
                        else {
                            t
                                .row($('tr[data-date="' + cell.data('date') + '"]'))
                                .data([
                                    null,
                                    data[1],
                                    cell.text()
                                ]);

                            return;
                        }

                    }
                   else {
                        if (cell.text() == '') {
                            if ((cell.css('background-color', '#1BBF2A'))) {
                                var data = t.row($('tr[data-date="' + cell.data('date') + '"]')).data();
                                t.row($('tr[data-date="' + cell.data('date') + '"]')).remove().draw();
                                //t.row(cell.css('background-color', backgroundColour)).remove().draw();
                                return
                            }
                            else {
                                return
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            rowNode = t.row.add([
                                null,
                                date.format('dddd,MMMM DD,YYYY'),
                                cell.text()
                            ])
                                .draw()
                                .node();

                            $(rowNode).attr('data-date', cell.data('date'));
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
        }


         function LoadCalendar1() {
            var t = $('#CalendarSelection').DataTable();
            var date = new Date()
            var d = date.getDate(),
                m = date.getMonth(),
                y = date.getFullYear()
                 var year = $("#CalenderYear").val();
            if (year == "") {
                year = y;
            }
            else {
                year = year;
            } 
              var startdate = year + '-01-01';
            var startdate1 = new Date(startdate);
            var enddate = year + '-12-31';
            var enddate1 = new Date(enddate);
            // I skip some conditions whether to check the selected day either sunday or other days ..
             if (rr1 == 'Off Day') {
                        $('.fc-day.fc-Sun').css('backgroundColor', '#1BBF2A').text(rr1);
                    }

                    var arr = [];
                    for (i = startdate1; i < enddate1; i.setDate(i.getDate() + 1)) {
                        var New_SDate = i.getDay();
                           arr.push(([
                                null,
                                moment(i).format("dddd,MMMM DD,YYYY"),
                                rr2

                            ]));
                    }
                     for (k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
                        t.row.add([
                            null,
                            arr[k][1],
                            arr[k][2]
                        ]).draw();
                    }
            }
    </script>
```

As my code is too long, I edited and give the selected codes related to question,so if open close braces/parenthesis missing means typo error only. Where I did wrong? Kindly help.

Comment: Hi, it would be easier to debug the issue on codepen or fiddle. Can you please try to setup code there

Comment: @KhurramIshaque Hi sir, sry for late reply.I tried my code in fiddle,but mine is not working exactly in fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/jso2hbtp/  here is my link... As I never used fiddel earlier I dont know what did I do wrong...But related to my question, I found where the error occur..`if (($('tr[data-date="' + cell.data('date') + '"]').length > 0))` , In this line, I check whether my table have same date, checking using its length.. it works for individual selection, but for selection after bulk selection of days, when I debug, the condition satisfies with length>0, but cant go thro' loop